# Pandas extract hierarchical info?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which describes serial numbers of items arranged in boxes:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'barcode':['1000']*3+['2000']*4+['3000']*3, 'box_number': ['10']*2+['11']+['12']*4+['13','14','15'],'serials': map(str,range(800,810))})

  barcode box_number serials
0    1000         10     800
1    1000         10     801
2    1000         11     802
3    2000         12     803
4    2000         12     804
5    2000         12     805
6    2000         12     806
7    3000         13     807
8    3000         14     808
9    3000         15     809
```

I want to group them hierarchically to output to hierarchical XML, so that every barcode has a list of box numbers which each have list of serials in them.

So I did a groupby which seems to do exactly what I want:

```
df.groupby(['barcode','box_number'])['serials'].apply(' '.join)

barcode  box_number
1000     10                    800 801
         11                        802
2000     12            803 804 805 806
3000     13                        807
         14                        808
         15                        809
Name: serials, dtype: object
```

Now, I want to extract this info practically the way it is displayed so that I get a row for each barcode with data grouped similar to this:

```
row['1000']== {'10': '800 801','11':'802'}
row['2000']== {'12': '803 804 805 806'}
row['3000']== {'13': '807','14':'808','15':'809' }
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get this done. I tried reset_index(), another groupby() -- but this doesn't work on existing result as it is a Series, but I can't seem to be able to understand the right way.

How should I this most concisely? I looked over questions here, but didn't seem to find similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comrehension for get nested dictonary with [`Series.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.xs.html) and [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['barcode','box_number'])['serials'].apply(' '.join)

d = {lev: s.xs(lev).to_dict() for lev in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{'1000': {'10': '800 801', '11': '802'}, 
 '2000': {'12': '803 804 805 806'}, 
 '3000': {'13': '807', '14': '808', '15': '809'}}
```